# Turning an image into a graph

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I am doing watershed segmentation via scikit and now I need to determine the main (average) color of every segment and its position. The aim is to get a graph with the colors as vertices and weighted edges that illustrate the distance between segments. Can I do it with some scikit or opencv functions?

Comment: you can use `numpy.bincounts` to calculate sum and counts, and divide to get mean. Or you could check in scipy.ndimage as there is a selection of functions for doing things similar to this - see `center_of_mass` (I think it's called).

Comment: What you describe sound a lot like the Region Adjacency Graph functionality in scikit-image.  That said, you can also get color averages and position averages by using region properties (also implemented in scikit-image).